# Dual-boot, Win7 + 18.04?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I just installed Kubuntu 18.04 on an HP-Z420 which was running Windows7. When I finished the installation, I ejected the boot DVD, but on restart it just goes back into Windows. Shouldn't it have installed GRUB for me?

Comment: What is the boot order in bios?

Comment: Is this a BIOS/MBR system or an UEFI/gpt configuration? Post this: `sudo parted -l` If drive is gpt, then Windows has to be UEFI, and if MBR then Windows is BIOS boot. Fixes are different for BIOS and UEFI. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Most Windows 7 installs were BIOS/MBR, but a few are UEFI/gpt.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to **Setup the GRUB Menu**:

- Boot into Windows OS.
- Right click on "Start" and choose **Command Prompt (Admin)** to open command prompt. Or search for *Command Prompt* and run it as administrator.
- On the prompt window, run the command:

  ```
  bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
  ```

  and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

Once done, restart your system. You will start getting the GRUB menu. Thereafter, whenever you wish to switch between the OS, just reboot the system and select your preferred OS from the grub menu.